# AutoMapper - Problem in mapping models which the subfields are different objects

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Via AutoMapper, I want to convert `CreateUserInputModel` to `UserModel`.

`CreateUserInputModel` has a property: `List<int> Options` which accepts IDs of options. `UserModel` has a property: `List<OptionModel> Options` which contains the list of `OptionModel` which has the field `Id`. I tried to create a mapper `ForMember`, but when I add it to the mapper, an unusual error appears without exception.

[image: Mapping error]

If you have any ideas on how to resolve this mapping, I will be very grateful. Thank you!

CreateUserInputModel

```cs
public class CreateUserInputModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Firstname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Lastname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime EmploymentDate { get; set; }
    public int WorkTypeId { get; set; }
    public List<int>? Options { get; set; } = new List<int>();
}
```

UserModel

```cs
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Firstname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Lastname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int VacationDays { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmploymentDate { get; set; }
    public WorkTypeModel WorkType { get; set; } = new WorkTypeModel();
    public List<OptionModel>? Options { get; set; } = new List<OptionModel>();
}
```

User mapper

```cs
CreateMap<UserModel, CreateUserInputModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.WorkTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.WorkType.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Options, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Options.Select(option => option.Id).ToList()))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that you miss out on the mapping configuration for mapping from `int` to `OptionModel` and vice versa.

```cs
CreateMap<int, OptionModel>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
    {
        dest.Id = src;
    });

CreateMap<OptionModel, int>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => src.Id);
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6hVi3)